# I can not start my Ubuntu 15.04 pc after the update from yesterday the 18th off August to kernel 3.19.0-26

Tags: upgrade, kernel, updates, 15.04

at logon the system asks my password and wenn I give it the login screen is returning after a moment to ask it again.
Yes the password is the right one.
I reported the error message to launchpad but til now I didn't get a usable answer.
Can I do something with Grub to start the system on the earlier Kernal 
and how do I do that

thanks for answering.

Sorry if my Englisch is'nt the best my motherlanguage is Dutch

Comment: This is probably AMD driver issue. Boot with the previous kernel and wait for `fglrx-updetes`.

Answer (score 0):

Like described in [How to get to the GRUB menu at boot-time?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16042/how-to-get-to-the-grub-menu-at-boot-time) you can access the GRUB Menue by pressing <kbd>shift</kbd> - there you should be able to select prior installed and not removed kernels...